# Facebook - Security of Auth Token?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

How important is it to keep the oauth_token safe from prying eyes? For instance, should I avoid passing it around in javascript and keep it solely in php-land or is it fairly harmless to use it as is convenient? I'm trying to figure what nefarious things a user could do with it but beyond manually replying to their requests and looking up their own information it seems like it would be fairly harmless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oauth_token gives access to the account the token is bound to [1]. So it must be kept secret from anyone other that the owner of the account (and can be disclosed to him).

[1] Facebook uses OAuth2, and the access_token alone allows to use the API, without OAuth consumer key / secret.

Comment: So what you're saying is that so long as that user is the only one to see it then it shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: The oauth_token is useless without the token secret, consumer key and consumer secret. It's one piece of information that can uniquely identify an end user, but it can't be used to do anything without the additional fields needed for the signature.

Comment: I disagree Mark S. The token is not useless without the secret and key - it is generated based on the secret and key and then provides access to act on behalf of the entity it represents. Thus if an access_token that was generated on behalf of a user is exposed to the public, then anyone can use that access_token while it's still active to perform actions on the user's behalf. In many cases, `offline_access` has been granted and the user's access_token then has no session timeout.

Comment: @DSchultz: +1, the OP is just considering the possibility of the "current" authorized user manually manipulating the API request with *his* `access_token` but it becomes really dangerous when someone else get it (which is really easy without a secure browsing - HTTPS). Just a question @DSchultz: I noticed that FB doesn't relate/verify the `access_token` to the domain the owner app is configured for. Why is that?

Comment: @DSchultz: The access token cannot be used to get any data unless the request has the proper OAuth signature. The proper signature requires the secret and the key. Without those two, then you can't access the resource even if you have the access_token

Comment: @Mark S., Facebook uses OAuth2 (over ssl), which is different. Once we have the access_token, we just pass it as a GET or POST parameter to any request, without signature (ssl does the authentification). The advantage is that we can safely use the API in javascript on the client side without disclosing the consumer secret, and the impl is by far simpler.